# What do you call a function that returns 1, 0, or -1?

Tags: comparison, naming-conventions, naming

Is there a convention around naming functions that take a value and returns 1, 0, -1 given that value is a number?

```
function whatDoYouCallThis(value) {
  if (value < 0) return -1;
  if (value > 0) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is based upon Boolean logic

```
let value = 5;
if (value > 0) return 1; //true;
if (value == 0) return 0; //false
if (value <= 0) return -1; // still false 
the confusion comes from the -1 which is a shorthand method for:

if (value <= 0 && value != 0) // combination of two booleans
```

In computer science when true or false is the logic of a function it is a predicate function, whether or not this is considered a "pure predicate" function, I do not know, but as you can see the logic is boolean